# Regex, lookbehind/lookahead with ".*"

Tags: java, regex

This **word** has to be taken with the space  behind it
**word** like this has to be taken  too
If the **word** is like \gloss{word}, \(anything here)sezione{word}, \gloss{anything **word** anything), \(anything here)sezione{anything **word** anything}, it must not be taken.
If the **word** inside is like \(anything but gloss or sezione){**word**} and \{anything but gloss or sezione){strings **word** strings} it has to be taken.
Obviously aword, worda and aworda has not to be taken.

(**the bold word** has been taken, word has not)

I have problems in not catching the word that is inside "{.... word .....}"

My guess was `(?<!(sezione\{)|(gloss\{))(\b)( ?)word(\b)(?!.*\{})` so far, and I would have added a ".*" on the lookbehind and lookahead ( `(?<!(sezione\{)|(gloss\{).*)[...]` ) but like this it stops working.

If this matter, I plan to use Java's regex engine

Thanks in advance

edit: the major problem is

> \(anything here)sezione{anything **word** anything}

If I can NOT get this one, this should solve the whole problem

Comment: java's lookbehind implementation (afaik) is fixed width ie you must stipulate the exact number of characters to `lookbehind` for. Lookahead is not fixed width

Comment: So i can't use .* at all in lookbehinds? :c

Comment: No you cannot. You can only use `?` :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's set few hard facts about your use-case:

1. Java (and most of) regex engines don't support variable length lookbehind
2. Java regex engine doesn't support `\K` pattern that allows you to reset the search

In absence of that you will need to use a **workaround** which works in 3 steps:

1. Make sure input is matching expected `lookbehind pattern`
2. If it does then remove matched String by `lookbehind pattern`
3. In the replaced String match and extract your search pattern

Consider following code:

```
String str = "(anything here)sezione{anything word anything}";
// look behind pattern
String lookbehind = "^.*?(?:sezione|gloss|word)\\{";
// make sure input is matching lookbehind pattern first
if (str.matches(lookbehind + ".*$")) {
        // actual search pattern
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^}]*?\\b(word)\\b");
        // search in replaced String
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str.replaceFirst(lookbehind, ""));
    if (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        //> word
}
```

**PS:** You may need to improve code by checking for indexes in the input String for the starting point of search pattern.